# Login Does Not Work Because of Subdomain Cookie

Tags: login, session, cookie, enterprise-1.14

We have a multi site/store which is on a subdomain level (Magento v1.14.1.0):

```
main.com
store1.main.com
store2.main.com
```

Logging in without the main.com `frontend` cookie enables the login in store1.main.com. However, if main.com is visited, another `frontend` cookie is created with the same value of the other store cookie.

```
frontend | somehashvalueofthecookie | .main.com
frontend | somehashvalueofthecookie | .store1.main.com
```

I tried to set the value in `Cookie Domain` setting in Magento `Admin > General > Session Cookie Management` per store but it does not have an effect.

There's an accepted answer here [Can't login to second store on subdomain](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53314/cant-login-to-second-store-on-subdomain) but it didn't do the trick. I already removed the third-party extensions.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: set cookie domain as `.main.com` in system configuration

Comment: That is the reason why store1.main.com as part of main.com. store1.main.com should have an exclusive cookie/session, and main.com should not interfere in store1.main.com. Setting just "main.com" didn't do the trick, as stated in my last statement.

Comment: How are you setting up the multi-store at the entry `index.php` levels may help shed some light on the issue as it should work as you have mentioned.

Comment: This is why people who plan for the future tend to use `www` for the main site, it helps alleviate having to deal with this kind of nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookies created for main.com are acting as wildcard (`*.main.com`) and either merging or overwriting other sub-domain cookies.

You will have to use `www.main.com` for your main site

Comment: No if you change the cookie domain of the main store to `main.com` instead of `.main.com` should do the trick. as long as you delete all cookies beforehand

Comment: I did that @FabianBlechschmidt. Unfortunately, the `frontend` cookies for both stores are always having the same value, and the domains are always .main.com, and .store1.main.com even if I set the Cookie Domain per store in the Session Cookie Management setting. This can be reproduced in a fresh install of Magento 1.14.1.0. Also cleared the cookies to make sure it should take effect.

Comment: Either this is a bug or your make something wrong. If it is a bug, I would send it to magento and fix it, should be done easily=?